# npm update to specific version (and shrinkwrap)

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm using NPM and shrinkwrap  (latest up to date version) to maintain my packages.

At the moment, one of my package current version is 1.1.0.
The latest version of this package is 2.2.0.

I want to update/upgrade this specific package to version **2.0.0** (and not the latest 2.2.0).

I thought that the procedure would be:

1. `npm install` in order to make sure that I'm synchronized with the npm-shrinkwrap
2. `npm update myPackage@2.0.0`
3. `npm shrinkwrap`
4. `git add . && git commit -m "Updating package myPackage to version 2.0.0"`

This doesn't seem to be the right road to go. It doesn't update the `package.json` and it always jump to the latest version. I have no control over this command to select the specific version I want.

I read the documentation about `npm update` and couldn't find the proper way to update the package to a specific version.

How to do this ? Would `npm install --save myPackage@2.0.0` would be the correct procedure ? Then what will be the purpose of having `npm update` command ?

**Solution:**
`npm install package@2.0.0 --save`

Answer (score 77, accepted):

`npm update` doesn't seem to interact with the shrinkwrap file as far as I can tell. But you can use `npm install` to set the version of a package.

This will update both *package.json* and *npm-shrinkwrap.json*:

`npm install myPackage@2.0.0 --save`

Comment: In some old NPM version, it wasn't working. Since it was fixed, now it works.

Comment: When I execute the command. I got this error `npm ERR!  404 Not Found: myPackage@2.0.0 `

Comment: @BhavinThummar `myPackage` is just a placeholder. Replace `myPackage` with the name of the package that you're trying to update.

Comment: hi all, I'm doing this and I have no question this seems correct, but I ran the npm install and it does not seem to change my npm-shrinkwrap.
if I ran npm shrinkwrap it updates my file but it changes more packages than the ones I want to change. any idea?

Answer (score 10):

You can enter to `package.json`and write the version yourself on the dependencies. After that do `npm install` and it will install the correct version.

Comment: Of course, but I would like to avoid writing manually in the `package.json` and only use the NPM commands

Comment: You should not update versions in package.json by hand, it can break your build. See here https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/issues/330#issuecomment-511389429